# How to display a 404 page in deployed Yesod / Keter App

Tags: haskell, yesod

When I use `yesod devel` and go to a non-existent page I get a Not Found page (404). However, when I deploy the app with Keter, I get this

```
Error connecting to gateway:

InternalIOException connect: does not exist (Connection refused)
```

Since Keter (https://github.com/snoyberg/keter) manages the Nginix configuration, I am not sure what's the best way to resolve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug in Keter. Can you file an issue on the tracker?

**EDIT**

@Ecognium opened [this issue on the tracker](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/issues/28). The problem appears to be a bug in GHC 7.4.1 manifesting in the underlying application, not a bug in Keter itself.